# ¿Cómo mostrar una imagen de Google Drive o Google Photos en mi sitio web?

Tags: html, wordpress, google-drive

Hasta ahora tengo mis fotos en Flickr y muchas de ellas son usadas en mi página web, la cual está alojada en hosting compartido y es manejada con Wordpress.

Hasta hace poco Flickr era gratuito e ilimitado en cuanto al almacenamiento y en cuanto a la cantidad de fotos. Pero esto ha cambiado y ahora, en las cuentas gratis Flickr permitirá un máximo de 1,000 fotos.

He pensado pasar mis fotos a Google, pero no encuentro la forma de colocarlas en mi sitio web como imágenes normales (usando `src`). El problema es que Google no muestra la URL y la extensión del archivo para poderlo colocar como imagen. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?

En algunos sitios recomiendan hacerlo así:

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=ID-DEL-ARCHIVO" />
```

O bien:

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=ID-DEL-ARCHIVO />
```

A mi me funciona en local, pongo el código con un id de imagen válido y la imagen se muestra en mi editor de HTML, pero no en mi sitio web. La imagen no se muestra y en la consola aparece el error:

> **Failed to load resource: demasiados redireccionamientos HTTP**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna forma de hacerlo funcionar en mi entorno remoto?

Comment: sugiero revisar este link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557392/how-do-i-display-images-from-google-drive-on-a-website

Comment: Gracias @Tegito123, ¿sabes lo que es `GDrives`? No quisiera pasar por opciones de terceros. En ese caso prefiero intentar hacerlo a través de la API de Google Drive. Estoy tratando de evitar la API para algo que parecía podía ser sencillo.

Comment: desconosco que es GDrives apenas y lo escucho.. comentame que es

Comment: @Tegito123 la respuesta que enlazas hace referencia a `GDrives`, pero parece algo exterior a Google. Sería entonces pasar las fotos por un código de terceros que no se sabe cuánto tiempo vaya a funcionar. En ese caso preferiría pasar a usar la API de Google Drive, escribiendo mi propio código.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La solución que halle fue hacerlo publico la imagen para que sea visible:
subes una imagen a tu Google Drive, sobre dicha imagen das click derecho:

[image: select shared]

Escogemos la opción: More..

[image: public image]

La definimos como public con esto me permite acceder al ID de  mi imagen coloco Save y regreso a la pantalla anterior, en donde me provee un link dicho link esta conformado por mi ID :

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13aW1fV26g2nQOoAiYPH5v7dnN0m3keLM/view?usp=sharing
```

En este caso mi ID va después de :

```
d/
```

es decir mi id seria:

```
13aW1fV26g2nQOoAiYPH5v7dnN0m3keLM
```

para mostrar la imagen en mi web seria algo asi:

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id=13aW1fV26g2nQOoAiYPH5v7dnN0m3keLM">
```

espero te sirva..y te ayude..!!

[Puedes verificarlo aqui.](http://jsfiddle.net/y1mtLfce/)

Puedes ver el resultado acá, quizá deberias verificar tu navegador o configuraciones del mismo, en lo personal uso, **Firefox 63.0.1 , Centos 7**
[image: Resultado]

Comment: No puedo hacer comentario aun pero agrego a la respuesta de Diego Avila el link a esta pagina que tiene un conversor de URL del drive a URL visible en tu sitio. Basicamente hace los pasos de extracción del ID y lo deja visible. [Conversor](https://clasicwebtools.com/articulos/programacion/host-fotos-GDrive.html)

Comment: Muchas gracias, he intentado lo anterior. Pero que pasa cuando necesito estar cambiando la imagen cada 3 semanas.
Ya que el ID que se genera es único y diferente. Alguien me podria explicar, por favor.

Comment: Puedes hacer uso de esto de un iframe y que ahi se muestren todas las imagenes que tienes en tu carpeta compartida de imagenes  Vista de la lista

<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=YOURID#list" width="700" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Vista en cuadrícula

<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=YOURID#grid" width="700" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Lea más en: https://thomas.vanhoutte.be/miniblog/embed-add-google-drive-folder-file-website/